# While creating Entity class why we cant take id as long type ? why we need to take it as Long Type?

Tags: hibernate

```
@Entity
public class Book {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String reader;
private String isbn;
private String title;
private String author;
private String description;
```

Well I am defining an domain class.But my doubt is here, in the id why we cant take it as primitive long type.why we need to take as `private Long id`;(Object Type) ?

Comment: No one said that, it can also be a `long`

Comment: Did you find any error with `long id`?

Comment: i have checked but its working.what is the difference if we take Long ?